# link bbpress forum discussion to blogposts

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have buddypress forum and userblog plugin.
When a member creates a discussion in the forum it has to relate to blogposts as the member later can create. Specific discussions should relate to specific blog posts.

Is it possible to create a link automatically in the diskussion (under a certain category), which will link to the page where the member can create blogposts (under same category as in the forum), so discussion and blogpost will be related ?

Automatically another link which is visible for other members should be generated in the discussion too. This link will link to a page where members can see all blogposts that are related to the discussion.

Is this possible ? and would like som ideas how to do it :-)

Michael Jensen